# Facebook Login android/ Api restriction

Tags: android, flutter, facebook, facebook-login

```
The app "MyApp" is in violation of Meta’s Platform Terms or Developer Policies and
```

has been restricted, as described below.

```
Platform Term 7.d - Screencast video is missing or incomplete.
```

How can I send them any screen-record of my app using facebook as they want since its currently restricted. How do I deal with this. Should I create a new App in Facebook Developer?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Here's what i did:

- clone the Facebook app
- use the new app to do the screencast
- post the screencast to resolve the violation on the original app
- when tout do this, the app is unlocked until fb review the video
- do another screencast of the original app
  I don't know if this last step is necessary but at least i now have the screencast of the original app if necessary